# Julia array comprehension memory usage

Tags: arrays, memory-management, julia, list-comprehension

I am using an array comprehension for defining a value of interest for elements of an array of a self defined type.

```
sum([value.interest for value in ArrayofMyType if condition])
```

This expression itself is in an iterative loop. This means that every cycle, this comprehension uses new memory. Also, the condition each time may impose different lengths for the resulting array, and defining a predefined array with fixed length outside the loop may not be the best way.

This yields an overhead each time the loop runs and I don't know how I can make this more efficient and make a better use of memory. Is there any way anyone can guide me with this? Comprehensions are stylistically convenient but I think not the most efficient in my case.

code style is that:

```
for i in 1:MAX_ITER
    ### Some code above
    sum([value.interest for value in ArrayofMyType if condition])     
    ### Some code below
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a generator expression (just omit the brackets):

```julia
sum(value.interest for value in ArrayofMyType if condition)
```

This does not create an intermediate array but an instance of type `Generator`. You can do

```julia
g = (value.interest for value in ArrayofMyType if condition)
```

to create such an object outside of a function call.  It implements the iterator interface, in particular the methods `start`, `next`, `done`, and some additional methods like `length`, and can thus be used everywhere an iterator is accepted.

If everything is *type stable*, the overhead compared to a hand written loop is approximately constant and negligible for larger arrays. Otherwise, the overhead can be large.

For short arrays, the overhead can still be significant and a hand written loop might be the better solution:

```julia
immutable A{T} x::T end

const a = [A(i) for i in 1:100]

mysum(a) = mysum(eltype(a), a)

function mysum{T}(::Type{A{T}}, a)
    sum = zero(T)
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(a)
        sum += a[i].x
    end
    return sum
end

using BenchmarkTools

@benchmark sum(e.x for e in $a)
@benchmark mysum($a)
```

This gives `50ns` vs `15ns` on my PC.

Comment: what is the mechanism behind this? Does it create an array?

Comment: No, it creates an instance of type `Generator`. You can do `g = (value.interest for value in ArrayofMyType if condition)` to get the object. It implements the iterator interface, e.g., the functions `start`, `next`, and `done`.

Comment: @tim: you might want to add that bit of info to your answer!

Comment: I restructured the answer and added the information from above comment.